# workflow not working when any other account is used apart from system account

Tags: workflow, workflow-manager

I have designed a simple workflow using workflow manager. It is a single stage workflow where only approval is required. 
The problem that i'm facing is that when i'm running the workflow with the system account, its triggering but when i use any other account, it throws error.

The is mentioned below :

Activity in progress

Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP Unauthorized to http://site/_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(guid'6c455ec3-7170-4986-93e5-0d7d27c73087') Correlation Id: 99371e71-4251-431a-8c52-ddef06b62b25 Instance Id: db265e60-a171-4337-8baf-0dc9ce99eca7

Kindly suggest what can be the issue

Comment: what workflow you made? 2010 or 2013? If 2010 you could try impersonate step or if it is 2013 you could try app step.

Comment: It's in 2013 and i have already tried using the app step,but it still is  not  working .